# IE Opens When I Use ChromeWebdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, selenium-chromedriver

I have tried searching, but have had no luck in finding a solution. I trying to get Selenium Grid to work on my local machine before placing nodes on other machines. Long story short when I try using the chromewebdriver IE opens.

Everything compiles but IE opens and not chrome. While trying to find the problem I used the driver.getCapabilities().getBrowserName() and it showed internetexplorer. I tried looking through the remoteWebDriver class but could not find where its capability was set to IE.

I've also tried coping and running some code from similar questions, but IE still opens. Any help would be appreciated.

Hub:
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar -role hub -port 4444

Nodes:

```
java -jar selenium-standalone-2.31.0.jar -role node -port 5555 -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=chrome,platform=WINDOWS -browser browserName=firefox,platform=WINDOWS
```

(I have also tried adding -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver={path to web driver} but had no luck)

Code:

```
WebDriver driver;
@Before
public void setUp()throws java.net.MalformedURLException{
    DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
    capability.setBrowserName("Chrome");
    capability.setPlatform(Platform.WINDOWS);
    driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new java.net.URL("http://localhost:5555/wd/hub"), capability, capability);
    driver.get("http://book.theautomatedtester.co.uk/chapter1");
}
```

Comment: Browser you registered was under the name "chrome" and capability has "Chrome". Ideally this should throw a no browser available. Also, does your grid have any IE nodes registered?

Comment: AJ, I can't thank you enough...by using a lowercase 'c' Chrome opened up.

Answer (score 0):

Browser you registered was under the name "chrome" and capability has "Chrome". Ideally this should throw a no browser available